# A Test of Musical Knowledge

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, music

> *We're a real party people,
>
>   An American creation;
>
>   Our seven parts combined
>
>   Became a musical sensation.*

**Who are we?**

Comment: Seems to me that this could be any American [seven-member band](https://www.google.com/search?q=7-member%20band&rct=j)...

Comment: I recognize that the wording makes the question look rather ambiguous, but keep in mind that *everything* before you is important, and the answer will be unambiguously more correct than any others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are

> the seven [Founding Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_Fathers_of_the_United_States):
> John Adams, Benjamin Franklin, Alexander Hamilton, John Jay, Thomas Jefferson, James Madison, and George Washington

---

We're a real party people,

> They advocated political parties (Tea Party).

An American creation;

> They founded America.

Our seven parts combined
Became a musical sensation.

> Two musicals ([*1776*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1776_(musical)) and [*Hamilton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton_(musical))) were written about the Founding Fathers.

Comment: I feel like this answer doesn't adequately explain "seven parts combined".   I realize this may seem nitpicky, but in view of the brevity of the riddle, I think that each line deserves a thorough gloss.